# Error in creating twitterizer app in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, twitter-oauth

I am using Twitterizer dll to post a twit on twitter via oauth method but it give me error.
"Whoa there!
There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake."

And my code is:

```
using System;
using Twitterizer;
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var oauth_consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    var oauth_consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
    {
        OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret,
            Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://Twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token+{0}", reqToken.Token));
    }
    else
    {
        string requestToken = Request["oauth_token"].ToString();
        string pin = Request["oauth_verifier"].ToString();
        var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret, requestToken, pin);
        OAuthTokens accessToken = new OAuthTokens()
        {
            AccessToken = tokens.Token,
            AccessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret,
            ConsumerKey = oauth_consumer_key,
            ConsumerSecret = oauth_consumer_secret
        };
        TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(accessToken, "Hello everyone, today it's too hot (weather)!!!");
        if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
        {
            Response.Write("It's done");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Fail");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please help me..

Comment: Why would anyone put a -1 on such a question?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing no one is giving an answer to your problem, I can suggest the library I am working on.

With Tweetinvi you will be able to do what you want with the following code :

```
// Step 1 : Redirect user to go on Twitter.com to authenticate
public ActionResult TwitterAuth()
{
    var appCreds = new ConsumerCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET");

    // Specify the url you want the user to be redirected to
    var redirectURL = "http://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/Home/ValidateTwitterAuth";
    var authenticationContext = AuthFlow.InitAuthentication(appCreds, redirectURL);

    return new RedirectResult(authenticationContext.AuthorizationURL);
}

// Step 2 : On redirected url
public ActionResult ValidateTwitterAuth()
{
    // Get some information back from the URL
    var verifierCode = Request.Params.Get("oauth_verifier");
    var authorizationId = Request.Params.Get("authorization_id");

    // Create the user credentials
    var userCreds = AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(verifierCode, authorizationId);

    // Do whatever you want with the user now!
    ViewBag.User = User.GetAuthenticatedUser(userCreds);
    return View();
}
```

Authentication Documentation : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Authentication

I know this is not helping for your Twitterizer but you might want to consider it.